# Input difference for finding the subset

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, input, subset

Trying to understand the need of having `num_sets` needed in my A, B input code in order to get True or False if A is a subset of B based on input.

```
T = int(input())
for num_sets in range(T):
    num_sets, A = input(),set(input().split())
    num_sets, B = input(),set(input().split())
    print(A.issubset(B))
```

Code block works when it has `num_sets, A` or `num_sets, B`. When I have the line of code as `A = input(),set(input().split())` and `B = input(),set(input().split())` it doesn't work and I get a error message stating, `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'issubset'.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `num_sets` inside the loop. When you write:

```
num_sets, A = input(),set(input().split())
num_sets, B = input(),set(input().split())
```

this is the same as:

```
num_sets = input()
A = set(input().split())
num_sets = input()
B = set(input().split())
```

You aren't using `num_sets` after that and the `for` loop sets a new value for `num_sets` on each iteration, so all this is really accomplishing is making you enter an extra line, twice, and then ignoring the input.

The reason this isn't working as expected:

```
A = input(),set(input().split())
```

is because the right side of that assignment is actually a `tuple`, and because the left side isn't, `A` is getting both values. If you answered the first `input()` prompt with "1", and the second `input()` with "2 3", your result in `A` would be:

```
('1', {'2', '3'})
```

which isn't a `set`, so `A.issubset(B)` gives an error.

I think what you probably want is this:

```
for num_sets in range(T):
    A = set(input().split())
    B = set(input().split())
    print(A.issubset(B))
```

which will allow you to enter two groupings of values, and print whether `A` is a subset of `B`.